# Select MAX(ID) não funciona corretamente

Tags: mysql

Alguém sabe me dizer porque este `SELECT` abaixo no `MYSQL` está pegando o maior `ID` corretamente, mas os campos (valor, data e status) não trazem as informações do maior `ID` retornado. O `SELECT` está pegando o maior `ID`, mas as informações dos campos (`valor`, `data` e `status`) retornados são de outro `ID`.

```
SELECT max(id), valor, afiliado_id, data, status FROM afiliado_saque_logs WHERE afiliado_id = 27
```

E quando eu faço da forma abaixo colocando o (`afiliado_id = 27`) referente a pessoa que eu quero trazer o maior `ID` com os campos (`valor`, `data`, `status`) aí não retorna nada, sendo que existem informações para o `afiliado_id = 27`.

```
SELECT id, valor, afiliado_id, data, statusFROM afiliado_saque_logsWHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM afiliado_saque_logs) and afiliado_id = 27
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query 1:**

Isso está acontecendo porquê você está procurando pelo afiliado_id 27.
A sua consulta trás o maior id que existe na base, mas os dados ele recupera do usuário 27.

**Query 2:**

Sua consulta está procurando a linha onde o id é o maior número e o afiliado_id for 27.
Não está retornando nada porquê provavelmente o afiliado_id 27 não possui o maior id.

Caso queira que a primeira query funcione corretamente e retorne os dados do maior id encontrado você pode substitui-la por:

```
SELECT id, valor, afiliado_id, data, status FROM afiliado_saque_logs WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM afiliado_saque_logs)
```